# Row merging over strings in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a phone directory that stores Department, Title, Email and Extension on seperate rows, the things being in common are First and Last Name. I have combined First and Last Name as a Key, and would like to merge the rows to where you would end up with a single row with the Name, Title, Department, Email and Extension.

I have tried creating a dictionary for each key, but I have not had any luck with the actual merging. This is where I am on coding it. I had to clean the data first to get the appropriate columns.

the table looks like the following:

```
LastName  FirstName  Department Title   Extension Email           Key
Doe       Jane       HR         Officer 0000                      Jane Doe
Doe       Jane       HR         Officer           jdoe@email.com  Jane Doe
```

```
df = pd.read_excel("Directory.xlsx")
df = df.drop(columns = ["group_name","editable","id","contact_type","id2","account_id","server_uuid","picture",
             "dial_prefix","name","label","id3","transfer_name","value","key","primary","label4","id5",
             "type","display","group_name6"])

df = df.rename(index = str, columns = {"last_name":"Last Name","first_name":"First Name","location":"Department",
               "title":"Title","dial":"Extension","address":"Email"})

df["Key"] = df["First Name"].map(str) + " " + df["Last Name"].map(str)
```

```
LastName FirstName Department Title   Extension Email          Key  
Doe      Jane      HR         Officer 0000      jdoe@email.com Jane Doe
```

Comment: Please add real names, `somestr` is not making your question clear and what you try to achieve. Try to fix your question so we can help you better.

Comment: Thanks Erfan, I just edited, hopefully it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we use [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to replace the whitespaces with `NaN`. Then use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and apply [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with methods `backfill` and `forwardfill` to fill in your empty spaces. Finally we can use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to get the single row as wanted.

```
df['Key'] = df['FirstName'] + ' ' + df['LastName']
df.replace('', np.NaN, inplace=True)
df = df.groupby('Key').apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')).drop_duplicates()

print(df)
  LastName FirstName Department    Title Extension           Email       Key
0      Doe      Jane         HR  Officer      0000  jdoe@email.com  Jane Doe
```

Comment: Thanks Erfan, that worked. I am relatively new to data science in Python and am still trying to learn the necessary packages.